# Getting TypeError: update_token() missing 1 required positional argument: 'token'

Tags: python

I´m new to Python and programming overall. This is one of the projects of the bootcamp I'm currently attending and I keep getting this error. It's supposed to create a new token and then use it in the function post_new_client_kit. I've tried sending the update_token function to the data.py file and then calling it back in the current file but I keep getting the same error.

```
import data
import configuration
import requests


def post_new_user(body):
    return requests.post(configuration.URL_SERVICE + configuration.CREATE_USER_PATH,
                         json=body,
                         headers=data.headers)


# Función para actualizar el token
def update_token(token):
    headers = data.headers.copy()
    headers["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {token}"
    return headers


def post_new_client_kit(kit_body):
    auth_token = update_token()
    return requests.post(configuration.URL_SERVICE + configuration.KITS_PATH,
                         json=kit_body,
                         token=auth_token,
                         headers=data.headers)
```

I´m sorry if these seems quite simple, but I've been stuck at this for 3 days now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `auth_token = update_token()` you are calling it empty but it is expecting a param, right?

Comment: Also, the ``requests.post()`` function does not have a token keyword argument.

Comment: What exactly does your error message look like?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.